# Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am hosting my Discord Bot in Replit. And, I am using `node-html-to-image` package for converting the html to jpeg. When I tried it in the `localhost`, it works perfectly. But when I try it in Replit, it returns this error:

```
(node:250) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to 
launch the browser process!
```

Here is the code I am using, `htmltoPng.js`:

```
const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");
const nodeHtmlToImage = require("node-html-to-image");

const puppeteer = { args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas', '--no-first-run', '--headless', '--no-zygote', '--disable-gpu'], headless: true, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true };

module.exports = async (msg, user, data) => {
  const _htmlTemplate = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Poppins", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: rgb(22, 22, 22);
        color: #fff;
        max-width: 300px;
      }

      .app {
        max-width: 300px;
        padding: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        border-top: 3px solid rgb(16, 180, 209);
        background: rgb(31, 31, 31);
        align-items: center;
      }

      img {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <img src="${user.username}" />

      <h4>Welcome ${msg.author.username}</h4>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
`;

  const images = await nodeHtmlToImage({
    html: _htmlTemplate,
    quality: 100,
    type: "jpeg",
    puppeteerArgs: puppeteer,
  });

  return msg.channel.send(new MessageAttachment(images, `${name}.jpeg`));
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks !

Comment: does [This issue on github](https://github.com/frinyvonnick/node-html-to-image/issues/100) help?

Comment: I looked upon that, but it also doesn't work! (See updated question/code)

Answer (score 0):

Your goal here is to create a welcome card and then post it in a channel, right? Why not use canvas for this, which is alot faster and efficient? Theres even this guide online that specifically targets discord:

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/canvas.html#setting-up-canvas

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! But I also had other uses too. The alignment of things is canvas is not easy. I want to use html/css combination

Comment: @AjitKumar canvas uses similar styling rules of CSS. Using a browser for this task is overkill. If you want to preview a webpage and show it in discord, you can use google's API for this. If you want to do it in house, try running your node process using sudo, maybe then the process will be able to fire up

Comment: Can you help me with that `sudo` process ?

Comment: @AjitKumar just do `sudo nodejs yourproject.js`

Comment: I tried but it gives this error: `sh: 1: sudo: not found
exit status 127`

Comment: This is old but I change mine for canvas and it's faster and do not need chronium to work! Thanks! @lolc

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The package `node-html-to-image` currently uses `pupeteer 3.0.0` which does not include all the necessary dependencies. This is fixed in `pupeteer 3.0.4`.

## Solution

You can install the necessary dependencies while you wait for the package to update.

`sudo apt-get install -y libgbm-dev`

## Links

Here is the issue for `node-html-to-image`
https://github.com/frinyvonnick/node-html-to-image/issues/91

Here is the issue on the pupeteer side https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/732#issuecomment-614809415

## Update

The pull request was accepted. `node-html-to-image` v3.2.0 should work for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29146498)

Comment: @camille sorry for the laziness does this look better?